# Avoiding multiple implementations of the same method in different context

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, inheritance

I have a simple design question. I am not sure how to design the following "situation" with respect to scalability and object-orientation.

```
interface IA {
  void update();
}

class A implements IA {
    public void update(){
        updateInX();
        updateInY();
    }

    private void updateInX(){
      ...
    }

    private void updateInX(){
      ...
    }
}
```

The redundancy (updateInX(), updateInY()) seems like a bad design, but I have no idea how to improve it. I would appreciate your help!

Comment: It's not completely clear what you're asking. Are you saying you're not happy with constantly re-writing `updateInX/Y()` ?

Comment: @Chris. Exactly! X and Y are examples. I could have A, B, C ... X, Y, Z etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem can be solved using [Template method design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern). You will basically define abstract class which contains abstract methods which has to be overriden and leave the computation itself on the abstract class. For instance

```
public abstract class Something {

    public void update(){
       updateInX();
       updateInY();
       printResult();
    }

    private void printResult() {
        //print
    }

    protected abstract void updateInX();
    protected abstract void updateInX();
}
```

This will make a child object implement only necessary methods and leave the computation on the base class.

Comment: I will try it tomorrow (template method design pattern) and accept your answer. Thank you!